# How does ASP.NET MVC arbitrate between two identically named views (aspx and razor)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using ASP.NET MVC3 I created a new Razor view and gave it the same name as the existing .aspx view that I had been using. I noticed that controller continued to pick up the .aspx view (which has the same name as the action) which is pretty much what I expected. I then renamed the .aspx view and action picked up the razor .cshtml view.

So if I have two views called myview.aspx and myview.cshtml and an Action called MyView() that does a return View(), it will pick up the myview.aspx view and return that.

How does MVC3 decided which view-type to default to?
Is there a way to change this default behavior to prefer a razor view over an .aspx view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything stems down to the order of view engines in the `ViewEngines.Engines` collection. Here's how the [`ViewEngines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewengines.aspx) static constructor looks like (as seen with Reflector in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM):

```
static ViewEngines()
{
    ViewEngineCollection engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
    engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
    engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
    _engines = engines;
}
```

which explains why WebForms is the preferred view engine.

So you could perform the following grotesque hack in `Application_Start` to inverse the preference towards Razor :-)

```
var aspxVe = ViewEngines.Engines[0];
var razorVe = ViewEngines.Engines[1];
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(razorVe);
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(aspxVe);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine its down to the order in which view engines are registered. Earlier registered view engines will be queried first. If you want to change the order:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, ...);
```